# Ruby Google Drive Authorization Error when Writing to a File

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, spreadsheet, google-drive-api

I'm using [google_drive](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) to download and manipulate Google Drive documents for seeding a Rails App. I can download spreadsheets as files and parse them without problems, however I want to save the spreadsheet locally.

```
require "google_drive"

# Log in to Google Drive
session = GoogleDrive.login("my.email@address.com", "MyPassword")

spreadsheet = session.spreadsheet_by_title('SpreadsheetName')

# At this point spreadsheet exists and I can manipulate it freely

spreadsheet.download_to_file('spreadsheet_name.xls')
```

As per the [readme](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/master/README.rdoc) I'm using [download_to_file](http://gimite.net/doc/google-drive-ruby/GoogleDrive/File.html#method-i-download_to_file), but encounter an Authorization Error:

```
/Users/*[me]*/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/google_drive-0.3.2/lib/google_drive/session.rb:429:in `request': Response code 401 for get https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=*[key]*: 

  <HTML> (GoogleDrive::AuthenticationError)
    <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
      <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
      <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
  </HTML>

  from /Users/Me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/google_drive-0.3.2/lib/google_drive/file.rb:153:in `download_to_io'
        from /Users/Me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/google_drive-0.3.2/lib/google_drive/file.rb:114:in `block in download_to_file'
        from /Users/Me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/google_drive-0.3.2/lib/google_drive/file.rb:113:in `open'
        from /Users/Me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/google_drive-0.3.2/lib/google_drive/file.rb:113:in `download_to_file'
        from db/seeds/modules.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems that auth is failing, but I am already authorized and have downloaded the file data.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: @LasseDahlEbert It's a known issue. See: https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/issues/34

Comment: Thanks, for the heads up - I had only searched the open issues to find clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue: https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/issues/34

> download_to_file uses different API, and it seems it only supports
>   downloading as HTML. To download as PDF, you need to write code to
>   fetch the URL you mentioned manually. You can probably use
>   session.request() method to reuse the authorization google-drive-ruby
>   provides.
>
> It would be nice to have that feature in google-drive-ruby. But the
>   API google-drive-ruby uses (Document List API) will be deprecated, so
>   I need to switch to Google Drive API. So I will implement that feature
>   after the switch (if it's available in Google Drive API).